# how to drag and drop dynamic objects by selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I have http://prntscr.com/nle3i9 this elements and they are dynamic, I want to handle every   and drag and drop them, I am using this code http://prntscr.com/nle3wy but it does not work.

Comment: I want to handle every object by tag <tr>

Comment: Try this https://www.guru99.com/drag-drop-selenium.html

Comment: What do you mean by "does not works"? Please share all information here, do not link to external pages to explain your problem

Answer (score 0):

List tr=driver.findelements(By.tagname("tr"))

use two for loops and iterate with one loop with increment